# Live video streams / How to resize (and move) them on click?

Tags: html, video, resize

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

I'm having simple html5 video streams running live on a website (Nr. 1-6). I would like, that the on click on one of these smaller thumbnails, that it will be displayed on top in the main bigger 'window'. I hope you understand what I mean. Is this even possible without any 3rd party tools?

Comment: Do you have any existing code to show us? Because what you should do, is set a data-video attribute on the little thumbs on the bottom, and on the click of this thumbnail, make javascript execute a function that looks for the data-video and sets it as the video src of your main frame.

Comment: Hi Steyn, unfortunately I don't have a example yet, because I basically only know how to add the videos into a HTML file. I just saw your Answer below. The HTML seems logic to me, however, where would I need to enter the JS part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be something like this (this example requires jQuery, just typing it out right here)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnail').on('click',function() {
    var videoSrc = $(this).attr('data-video');
    $('#mainFrame').attr('src', videoSrc);
  });
});
```

HTML parts needed:

```
<video id="mainFrame"></video>
<div class="thumbnail" data-video="URL_TO_VIDEO"></div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-video="URL_TO_VIDEO"></div>
```

This would assume you have the styling etc. already done

Comment: Steyn, thanks for this explanation: I'm currently stuck here-> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9ppv46nj/)

Comment: I've updated your fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/9ppv46nj/2/ inspect the code. It's really not that hard ;)

Comment: And for an example including actual images, check http://jsfiddle.net/9ppv46nj/3/

Comment: Wow!!! This is great! Thank you sooo much! I wonder if this would work that all the thumbnails are actually 'playing' and on click it would move to the main frame. Do you know if auto play works? Like when you hit the site for the first time that it starts with 'video' #1?

Comment: No problem! Would you mind upvoting and accepting my answer? Auto play works, you can actually set a src on the video right away like this http://jsfiddle.net/9ppv46nj/4/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having your thumbnails play right away since this would mean you have 6 videos playing simultaneously on your page, which takes a lot of traffic (both network and pc wise) for the user.

Comment: You are right...that would probably be too much! I can try to snap some stills from the live stream and update it from there..! Thanks a lot for all your help! This is amazing!

Comment: Hey no problem! I would love to see the product when it's finished! Do you have a URL I can have a look at?

Comment: Here's a screenshot. Its internal therefore URL wouldn't work! Its perfect - the thubmnails are auto updating with javascript from the stream source directly every 5 seconds. http://i.imgur.com/n3b4hz1.png